# T-SQL - Update any row of duplicates if none has has a column entry

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table that I like to *update* that every **NAME** has only one **ACTIVE** entry. The order doesn't matter.

---

**Given Table:**

```
| NAME   | ACTIVE |
|-----------------|
| Adam   | 0      |
| Adam   | 0      |
| Peter  | 0      |
| Peter  | 0      |
| Peter  | 0      |
| Mike   | 1      |
| Mike   | 0      |
| Phil   | 1      |
| Phil   | 1      |
```

---

**Desired Result:**

```
| NAME   | ACTIVE |
|-----------------|
| Adam   | 1      |
| Adam   | 0      |
| Peter  | 1      |
| Peter  | 0      |
| Peter  | 0      |
| Mike   | 1      |
| Mike   | 0      |
| Phil   | 1      |
| Phil   | 0      |
```

---

I would start to set **ACTIVE** to "0" on every row to remove duplicates like the *Phil* rows.

`UPDATE TABLE SET ACTIVE=0`

But how do I manage to only set every name only once to active?

Comment: This is hopefully just for some test and not a real system.

Comment: What is your business case here? Because the suggested answers both may set another record on 1, even when there was only one "1"-record. In case you would like to keep an "already 1"-record as a "1", they might not suffice. If it is arbitrary which row will become *the one*, they will suffice.

Comment: It's a table of user data from different sources that is (broken by design) used as a list for a mailing system. This table has a join to mail-subscriptions (on email address) and I need a "temporarily" workaround to get an unique user, otherwise a subscriber might get a mail multiple times. And unfortunately I can't work with an index here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats my approach:
i create a rownumber for each group (name) 
and finally just set rows with rownumber = 1 to active, all others to 0 = inactive

```
UPDATE UpdateTarget
   SET ACTIVE = IIF(RowNum = 1, 1, 0) -- set first occurance to active, others inactive
  FROM ( SELECT *
               ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY x.NAME) AS RowNum
           FROM mytable x
       ) AS UpdateTarget
 ;
```

i've also created a Rextester, so you can test my script: 
http://rextester.com/YWCOT10468

Answer (score 1):

You can update table this way and if you like to delete duplicates use the second query or select distinct records from query

```
with t as
(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over ( partition by name order by name ) row from YourTable t
) 

update t 
set active = case when row = 1 then 1 else 0 end 

;
```

-- For deleting  duplicate records

```
with t as
(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over ( partition by name order by name ) row from YourTable t
) 

delete t where row > 2
;

select * from YourTable
```